# Split a string by two different delimiters

Tags: java, string

I have this string.

```
One@two.three
```

I want to find the three different parts (*ignoring @*)

Past using `indexOf('@')` to find it, I'm not sure what to do next.
What other things like `indexOf()` could I use?

Comment: Do you want to split the text by non-word characters? Take a look at the `split` method then.

Answer (score 0):

> What other things like indexOf() could I use?

You need `indexOf`

```
 String text = "One@two.three";
 int pos1 = text.indexOf('@');
 // search for the first `.` after the `@`
 int pos2 = text.indexOf('.', pos1 + 1);

 if (pos1 < 0 || pos2 < 0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();


 String s1 = text.substring(0, pos1);
 String s2 = text.substring(pos1 + 1, pos2);
 String s3 = text.substring(pos2 + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

```
final String input = "One@two.three";
for (String field: input.split("@|\\.")) {
    System.out.println(field);  
}
```

[Prints](http://ideone.com/zrphVC):

```
One
two
three
```